# Slidejs+php no start of slideshow + how to create pagination reference

Tags: php, jquery, slideshow

I try to implement slidejs to a page. Even though the images are loaded correctly and the show seems to start (my fade effect for the initial slide works), it doesn't progress to the next. Moreover, how could i create proper indexing for the dynamic fetching of the images, in the pagination part?
Here is the HTML/php code :

```
<div id="products">
<div class="slides_container">
 <div><img src="{$current_sale.images.default.detail.src}" alt="{$current_sale.Product.Brand.name} {$current_sale.Product.name}" /></div>
 {foreach from=$current_sale.images key=name item=images name=images}
  {if $name == 'default' || $images.mini.size != $current_sale.images.default.mini.size}
   <div><img src="{$images.mini.src}"/></div>
  {/if}
{/foreach}
</div>
<ul class="pagination2" >
{foreach from=$current_sale.images key=name item=images name=images}
 {if $name == 'default' || $images.mini.size != $current_sale.images.default.mini.size}
  <li><a href="#"><img src="{$images.mini.src}" /></a></li>
 {/if}
{/foreach}
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

and here the js (implemented inside the document.ready function):

```
$('#products').slides({
preload: true,
effect: 'slide, fade',
.
.
.
```